# Install win 10 AFTER ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have ubuntu running on a 240gb SSD, I have my home folder mounted on a secondary 960gb SSD.

I have a third 1TB HDD used for long term archiving of backups.

I now have a 4th 750GB HDD that I want to install win 10 on, I've been reading that Ubuntu should be installed second, I do NOT want to reinstall ubuntu at all to be honest. What is the best way to go about this?
Are there any caveats?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Comment: @Manoj that isn't for a sperate physical harddrive that's about dual booting on the same harddrive...

Comment: Ubuntu was recommended to be installed second to Windows just so you did not have to re-install grub.  This was mainly for legacy bios systems.  Windows seems to behave a bit better on UEFI systems, but always good to keep an Ubuntu installer USB handy if grub needs repair.  Windows can be picky on which drive it is installed to, does not like external USB drives(maybe better now).  As with all installs, double and triple check what you are doing first.